# Nuxt.js dynamic nested views and params

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I have a question about dynamic and nested routes in Nuxt.
I will create a kind of calculator. The user can choose a theme and get on the first dynamic routes - **called _slug.vue** - a dynamic navigation from the API about this theme and inside this navigation the user get the detail information about this theme.

On the `_slug.vue` page is also a dynamic navigation, from the REST API that trigger on the same page the  view like: `http://localhost/slug/slug2`

**first question:**
*user trigger a theme on startpage, get the navigation on _slug.vue*
How can I set the first menu item to active so that its content is displayed directly without the user having to click on the menu item first?

- the child-view has to be changed if user click to ther menu items
- child view can enter directly on browser and is also available

**second question**
I need to parse in the second step many params to create all user choices, to share the link to other users.

I will get this by creating vuex store "cart"

how can i implement this with the dynamic routes?

like:

```
http://localhost/slug/slug2?param1=test&param2=test2
http://localhost/slug/slug10?param1=test&param2=test2
```

You can see that the secondary slug is dynamic, the first slug is only dynamic by choosing this on startpage.

Here is my code:

**pages/index.vue**

```html
<template>
  <nav class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li
        v-for="(link, index) in links"
        :key="index"
      >
        <nuxt-link
          :to="link.shortName"
          :data-code="link.shortName"
        >
          {{ link.name }}
        </nuxt-link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</template>
```

**pages/_slug.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div class="calculator">
    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li
          v-for="(link, index) in $store.state.calculatorNavigation"
          :key="index"
        >
          <nuxt-link
            :to="{ path: '/' + $store.state.carResult.id + '/' + link.id}"
            :title="link.name"
            append
          >
            {{ link.shortName }}
          </nuxt-link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <nuxt-child></nuxt-child>
  </div>
</template>
```

**pages/slug/_category.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    here show the data for every menu point from the first /slug like /slug/slug2
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nuxt.js adding special classnames to all `nuxt-link` instances depending on the current location. By default it sets `nuxt-link-active` if current location starts with the URL of the `nuxt-link` and `nuxt-link-exact-active` if it is exact match ([classnames can be adjusted in config](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-router#linkactiveclass)).

In Dynamic Pages to get the params of the route you must use `asyncData`:

```html
<!-- pages/_slug.vue -->

<template>
  <h1>{{ this.slug }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    async asyncData({ params }) {
      const slug = params.slug // When calling /abc the slug will be "abc"
      return { slug }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The same way you could get the query string:

```html
<!-- pages/_slug.vue -->

<template>
  <h1>{{ this.slug }} / {{ this.param1 }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    async asyncData({ params, query }) {
      const slug = params.slug
      const param1 = query.param1 // When calling /abc?param1=test the param will be "test"
      return { slug, param1 }
    }
  }
</script>
```

In case you need to access route's params and query on the client-side as well, you can still use `$route` builtin (ie. for data fetching).

```html
<script>
  export default {
    mounted() {
      const slug = this.$route.params.slug
      const param1 = this.$route.query.param1

      // some fetching here
    }
  }
</script>
```

So, now the structure of your pages should be like this:

```
pages/
├── _slug/
│   ├── index.vue        -->  ie. http://localhost/slug/
│   └── _category.vue    -->  ie. http://localhost/slug/slug2
└── index.vue            -->  http://localhost/
```

So, in `_slug.vue` router parameter `slug` will be available. And in `_category.vue` both `slug` and `category` params will be available.

Comment: Implemented your page structure and with that it now works when I use this.$router.push, thus I am always redirected - dynamically - to the first page from the json. 

One question remains now, if I switch between the category but in the URL already have params (test=1 as an example), they disappear - is there a way to keep them?

thanks! :)